# opening password protected PDF document and rendering in android using new "PdfRenderer" class?

Tags: android, pdf, pdfrenderer

In Android 5.0, Google introduced the PdfRenderer class for rendering PDFs. I tried rendering the pdf using it and it worked. However, when it comes to password protected PDF i dint find a way to open it.

Has anyone done this or have any idea how to solve this issue. Please suggest.